# Where Do I Find Heroku SSH Key Pass?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Creating a new rails application, created a new Heroku app, and it is asking for my password after I type 'git push heroku master'; I cannot remember my password- how do I go about doing this to move forward in this tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Heroku password reset form if you've forgotten your password? https://id.heroku.com/account/password/reset

Comment: It's asking for the password for the SSH Key 'id_rsa'; I already tried entering my password for the Heroku site, not working.

Comment: I've removed the SSH Key using 'heroku keys:clear' and it's still giving me the password prompt.

Comment: ah, sorry - misread the question, when you created your ssh key it would have asked for a passphrase, if it's prompting you for one then you set one when you created your key. If you've forgotten it, create a new key and add it.